# How does Storm assign a task ID?

Tags: apache, apache-storm, topology

I've been trying to understand how Storm assigns a task ID to a bolt.

from this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/7P23beQIL4c) it appears that "Task ids are assigned at topology creation and are static. If a task dies/restarts or gets reassigned somewhere else, it will still have the same id."

Indeed when I rebalance/restart my Topology the task IDs remain the same.

What I don't understand is *when* will the taskID change? And at what stage in the [lifecycle of the topology](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.4/Lifecycle-of-a-topology.html) (which wasn't very intuitive to understand) is this ID assigned and by what logic?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out. I think.

Initially thought it could be random, but the taskID is the actual number of the executor thread based on the parallelism configured on all bolt and spouts of the topology.
If the topology is as such:
Spout A -> Bolt A -> Bolt B

and there are 10 threads of Spout A, 5 threads of Bolt A, and 1 executor thread of Bolt B, then the task ID of Bolt B would be 16.

The bolt will always be assigned this number as long as the total configuration of number of executors throughout the topology remains the same.